# How to remove extra space between  \vspace*{0em} and \section?

Tags: spacing, sectioning

I want to add an exact amount of space between type area and a section:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\KOMAoptions{fontsize=10pt, paper=14cm:21cm, DIV=calc, pagesize=auto, BCOR=5mm,     twoside=true, titlepage=true}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% shows frames of type area (good for debugging)
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

%\vspace*{-\topskip}  % removes \topskip space
\vspace*{0em}  % space amout is 0em for testing purpose; remove or comment to get absolutely no space
\section{Test}

\end{document}
```

I think the command `\vspace*{0em}` expands the section’s glue, right? If I remove `\vspace*{0em}` the section is on the top of the type area. Somehow `\vspace*{0em}` should do the same thing. The background is that I want to add an exact space between type area and section, but it’s always to much space. Any idea to fix this?

Comment: Inserting `\vspace*` necessarily inserts space (regardless of where it's issued) while `\vspace` is a little less invasive (see [Adding vertical space at the start of a page](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33370/5764)). Once you insert `\vspace*{0em}`, you already have "something" at the top of the page, followed by the regular `\section` top skip...

Comment: If you replace your `\vspace*{0em}` by `\hbox{}` (an empty box) you can see the same effect. This happens because `\section` inserts a vertical space at its top (which is discarded by tex if it is the first vertical material in a page, which is not the case after inserting `\hbox` or `\vspace*`). So the question should be "How can I remove the vertical space that the next command will insert?". I don't know the answer for this one.

Comment: @Werner I know that already, but how does this help?

Comment: @JLDiaz Yes, noticed this by replacing `\vspace*{0em}` with `\null`. Seems to have something to do with the definition of `\section`: `\newcommand{\subsection}{\@startsection{subsection}{1}{\z@}{-0.2ex}{2.3ex \@plus.2ex} ...`. Like you wrote: How to force LaTeX not to add extra space as there is no object before `\section`?

Comment: Please accept that there *is* an object before `\section` if you insert one with `\null` or `\vspace*`. This might be an argument from a technical POV, but you won't be able to change anything about that.

Comment: But one could redefine the \section environment (actually I use \addsec from KOMA Script) to remove the space before. How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My own not perfectly working solution is:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\KOMAoptions{fontsize=10pt, paper=14cm:21cm, DIV=calc, pagesize=auto, BCOR=5mm, twoside=true, titlepage=true}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
% shows frames of type area (good for debugging)
\usepackage{showframe}

\makeatletter
% change definition of \section; remove space before
\renewcommand{\section}{\@startsection{section}{1}{\z@}%
  {-0.01ex}%
  {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
  {\ifnum \scr@compatibility>\@nameuse{scr@v@2.96}\relax
    \setlength{\parfillskip}{\z@ plus 1fil}\fi
    \raggedsection\normalfont\sectfont\nobreak\size@section}%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\vspace*{-\topskip}
\section{Test}

Test

\end{document}
```

The code redefines the `\section` command in the way that the space before is set to `-0.01ex` (must be a negative number to avoid paragraph indention). There is only a little bit space left. Remove or comment out `\vspace*{-\topskip}` to see test this.

Comment: Does any one know where the little extra space comes from?