# How to show margin distances in mm

Tags: margins, geometry

I would like to know the distance (in mm) of the margins I just set, and I would like them to be displayed in the document (for debugging purposes, of course).

I use the `showframe` option of the `geometry` package in order to denote the margins.  How do I get to display the margin values?

This is a **super** MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\begin{document}
\kant[1-10]
\end{document}
```

I would like it to be something like this (taken from [Golden Ratio for vertical poem positioning](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63157/golden-ratio-for-vertical-poem-positioning/63334#63334)):

[image]

Of course, I don't care about the text inside, just the margins (margin par, topmargin, innermargin, etc.)

Comment: Use the `layout` package.

Comment: As a follow-up to egreg's comment, see for example http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42371/margins-and-text-position/42381#42381 and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42329/displaying-page-construction-guides/42330#42330 and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17957/is-there-a-picture-showing-all-the-lengths-used-in-lists/17962#17962

Comment: @egreg Nice! :)  Now what about the `mm` instead of `pt`?

Comment: @MarioS.E. use the [`layouts`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/layouts) package (with a final "s").

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I easily display the dimensions of the text body?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98603/how-can-i-easily-display-the-dimensions-of-the-text-body)

Comment: @Werner Definitely related, but I'm not so sure if a duplicate: a big part of the problem for me was to get the data in `mm`

Comment: Also related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51396/overview-of-margins-in-koma-script-typearea

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Based on Gonzalo Medina' suggestion, and with a little bit of help with the documentation, I was able to achieve this with the [`layouts`](http://ctan.org/pkg/layouts) package:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper]{scrbook}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{layouts}

\begin{document}

\printinunitsof{mm}{\pagevalues}

\verb|\marginparwidth|: \printinunitsof{mm}\prntlen{\marginparwidth}

\pagediagram
\end{document}
```

With this result:

[image]