# printed margins not correspond with pdf

Tags: printing

I'm writing my thesis. My page layout:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper,openright]{report}
     \usepackage[inner=3cm,outer=2cm,tmargin=2.0cm,bmargin=2.0cm,includefoot, includehead]{geometry}
```

After printed, I measured the margins with ruler and margins are not good.its varies from printer to printer :s

Comment: Have a look at the printer setup. Often there is a scaling factor or an option to fit the paper size.

Comment: I sometimes have the same problem, and indeed it is (when I'm sending it to a copy center) it is standard 97%.

Comment: It is common when using Adobe Reader that it shrinks page at 97%, because it apparently thinks that A4 paper doesn't fit in A4 paper.

Comment: If you are using `hyperref`, add the option `pdfprintscaling=None`. At least for Adobe’s PDF reader, this affects the initial setting for page scaling in the print dialog.

Comment: Another thing to check is the paper size that the printer driver is configured to assume. For example, on English Linux installations, it is often US Letter paper instead of A4 paper.

Answer (score 1):

Well, first of all, **don't panic!**

Second, your configuration with the `geometry` package seems about right, so there shouldn't be any problems if *that is indeed what you want your margins to be*.  You can see this by also setting the option `showframe`, e.g.:

```
 \usepackage[inner=3cm,outer=2cm,tmargin=2.0cm,bmargin=2.0cm,includefoot,includehead,showframe]{geometry}
```

Furthermore, you can check your layout lengths with the [`layouts`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/layouts) package (see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/181049/how-to-show-margin-distances-in-mm))

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper]{scrbook}
\usepackage[inner=3cm,outer=2cm,tmargin=2.0cm,bmargin=2.0cm,includefoot,includehead,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{layouts}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\begin{document}
%Recto Page
\kant[1-3]

%Verso Page
\newpage
\printinunitsof{mm}{\pagevalues}
\verb|\marginparwidth|: \printinunitsof{mm}\prntlen{\marginparwidth}

\pagediagram
\end{document}
```

[image]

Third, a stated by @samcarter and @Arne, there is a tolerance related to every printer and even every sheet of paper!  So don't be so hard on yourself if you see some minor discrepancies.